# Regarding MAINFRAME bin files , how to read/compare any bin files?

Tags: wpf, mainframe

I am planning to create a sample application in .NET WPF which reads MAINFRAME bin files, compare files side by side and extract file content without losing any formatting.

Below questions would really be helpful for me to create an algorithm.

1. What were general encoding standards of a typical MAINFRAME bin file?
2. How we read a bin file, do we need to use any tool?
3. How do we find differences between two MAINFRAME bin files?
4. Will we be able to identify a MAINFRAME bin file without using any tool – meaning from file itself?
5. What kind of output files are generated/read by MAINFRAME , meaning is it restricted to generate only “.bin” file or any other extension as well?

Please also provide me any open source editor which does the reading/writing/editing of a MAINFRAME bin file which can be a starter.

Record editor is one of the application which I use for some of my bin files although it seems to be incompatible for some bin files.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by doing this compare?

Comment: We process many files per month, in those we may receive possible duplicates or some corrupted. In order to identify possible duplicates and know the differences , we have to compare both the files.

Comment: If you are already receiving and correctly processing the files, what problem do you have in comparing them?

Comment: Big picture , we are SSIS folks, we process many kinds of files. For bin files we are finding it hard read or compare in our local machines without any tool other than executing the package alone and testing the data after it loads.
Imagine if we have more than 1 lakh records , how much time it will load, when can we compare?
In server we do have VEDIT tool where we can open/read/edit , although it is restricted access.

Comment: 100,000 records is not very many for a Mainframe :-) If you have data files from a Mainframe and they contain non-character data, that is asking for trouble. It is not clear what you are comparing. You have a file as a "control" and you compare a new file to it to confirm software changes are as expected? What, exactly and concretely, do you mean by bin files in your context?

Comment: Hi Bill,
Bin as binary files and yes these files do contain non-character data. There were scenarios , where we need to compare last month data with current month and highlight the differences. We are generate files in deed mainframe datasets which requires post validation , for which we require a tool. Anyways i assume we dont have a tool as such to compare these mainframe datasets. we got VEDIT tool to open such kind of files , mock them up although this tool requires licensing which is kind of a problem,

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no such thing as a "MAINFRAME bin file" - mainframe datasets neither have the concept of filetypes nor of file-extensions. After transfering files from the mainframe to some Windows/Unix-machine some people use the `.bin`-extension to indicate that the content should be treated as binary.

Some things you should know about mainframe-files (I'm mostly talking of fixed-recordlength sequential datasets, the most basic kind of dataset):

1. There is no common file-format, usually each mainframe-program rolls its own record-descriptions and writes those to a file. To make sense of the file you have to know the record-description.
2. You can read those files with any tool that is able to process an arbitrary sequence of bytes - but again: to make use of it you must interpret those bytes somehow.
3. Mainframe-datasets don't have some newline-character(s) to indicate the end of one data-record and the beginning of the next. Most datasets used for transfer have a fixed number of bytes per record, so the reading program has to split the read bytes at appropriate places. (There are also varying-recordlength-files, but I'll skip these for now).
4. Character-data on mainframes is usually encoded using some EBCDIC-characterset opposed to ASCII as used on PC-platforms. So you'll have to convert those for PC-based processing
5. Other sections might contain packed-decimal numeric data - each digit occupies a half byte ("nibble") and the last nibble indicates the sign of the number. E.g. `-4387` might be stored in 3 bytes as `04 38 7D`.
6. Your files might also contain raw binary or floating-point data - we can't tell, you'll have to ask the creator of the file.

To sum it up:

- you can't recognize or process them with some out-of-the-box-tool
- you have to know the record-description to do anything useful
- you'll have to cope with lots of mainframe-specific stuff

For most usecases, transferring raw binary files from mainframe to PC is not feasible. Better create EBCDIC-text-based files on the mainframe, use your filetransfer-tool to convert them to ASCII while transferring and process the text-data.

Comment: Thanks piet, your explanation seems to answer most of my questions. Although would you be able to direct me to any open source tool which does the job of creating EBCDIC -> convert to ASCII -> Data?

Comment: For data conversion, I would recommend using iconv. It converts from one code page to another. You will need to know what code page your mainframe code is in (there are many variants of EBCDIC). If you don't know, then start with IBM-1047 and convert it to ISO8859-1 (that's American EBCDIC and ASCII respectively), although IBM-037 might work better than IBM-1047.